# Context.User.Identity.Name null even after user authentication in identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

I am trying to send message to specific user in blazor server using signalR.
But the problem is that `Context.User.Identity.Name;` and `Context.UserIdentifier;` is null even after user is authenticated using `Identity`. And putting `[Authorize]` attribute in hub gives an error saying `Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).`
A help with my code will be great, Thank you.
Below is my hub

```
namespace WebChat.Hubs
{
    [Authorize]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task Send(string message, string user)
        {
            await Clients.User(user).SendAsync("Receive", message);
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var getUserName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            var getUserIdentifier = Context.UserIdentifier;
            UserHandler.UserList.Add(getUserName);
            UserHandler.UserList.Add(getUserIdentifier);
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
    }
    public static class UserHandler
    {
        public static List<string> UserList = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Below is my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
        {
            opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

Below is my razor component

```
<AuthorizeView>
    Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name! //<----- Shows logged-in user email
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            User:
            <input @bind="userInput" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
             Message:
            <input @bind="messageInput" size="50" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <button @onclick="Send" disabled="@(!IsConnected)">Send</button>

    <hr>
    <ul id="messagesList">
        @foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            <li>@message</li>
        }
    </ul>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the authorize attribute to work properly on normal controller actions?

Comment: has the user actually been logged-in yet?

Comment: @KingKing :yes user has logged-in

Comment: Please show your `hubconnection` code.

Comment: @BrianParker:             hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
             .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"))
             .Build();

            hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
            {
                var encodedMsg = $"{user}: {message}";
                messages.Add(encodedMsg);
                StateHasChanged();
            });

Comment: I believe the hubconnection needs to be configured to use the token. In your previous question I linked how to do this in WASM. I have not done this on server-side but the token would still be needed.

Comment: @sudip chand, I've posted a complete solution in your previous question. Later on I'll post some explanation and then upload my project to github.

Comment: @enet I didn't find the explanation in my previous question

Comment: See my answers. (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152891/enet?tab=answers). I always delete my answers if they are not being accepted. You've failed to accept my answer, so I've deleted it. I'll undelete it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the cookies into the server when connecting to the hub. See example below.

```
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
   .WithUrl("https://localhost:44313/signalr-hubs/messaging", options =>
     {
       if (HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
         {
           foreach (var cookie in HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies)
            {
              options.Cookies.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Key, cookie.Value, null, "localhost"));  
            }
         }
}).Build();
```